# knockout jquery program not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have written the following MVC application.

Index method returns just View() nothing more than that.

I am following some video tutorials to learn Knockout js and following is the code.

```
<script id="tagsTempl" type="text/html">
    <ul>
        {{each tags}}
            <li class="tagItem">
                <span>${Name}</span>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="tag-edit">Edit!</a>
                    <a href="#" class="tag-delete">Delete!</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

The following is my JavaScript file.

```
$(function () {
    var data = [
        { Id: 1, Name: "Ball Handling" },
        { Id: 2, Name: "Passing" },
        { Id: 3, Name: "Shooting" },
        { Id: 4, Name: "Rebounding" },
        { Id: 5, Name: "Transition" },
        { Id: 6, Name: "Defense" },
        { Id: 7, Name: "Team Offence" },
        { Id: 8, Name: "Team Defence" }
    ];

    var viewModel = {
        tags: ko.observableArray(data),
        tagToAdd: ko.observable(""),

        addTag: function () {
            this.tags.push({ Name: this.tagToAdd() });

        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

I am not getting the desired output but just the following junk.
[image]

Basically, I could not understand {{each tags}} loop, and I could not get proper resource in the internet. Can anybody please suggest me the right solution.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have referenced `jquery.tmpl.js` as the [`documentation`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-6-using-jquerytmpl-an-external-string-based-template-engine) shows. And here's a [`working jsfiddle example`](http://jsfiddle.net/EPpPU/).